# How does PassengerBaseURI works in Sub URI Deployment with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, web-deployment

I have gone through the passenger documentation about Sub URI Deployment and also read about `PassengerBaseURI` deployment option. But the thing is I don't understand how passenger would negotiate with rails action about routing. I am not sure negotiate is the right term. But this is something that always makes me wonder, will passenger tell the rails router that the `sub-uri` should be skipped or the passenger will remove the `sub-uri` before even reaching rails router.

I'll be super glad and grateful if someone can dissect this and explain. Thanks in advance.